# Deleting a "Zombie" bot from the Azure Portal

Tags: botframework

I created a bot via botframework.com. I no longer needed it and deleted it, also via botframework.com. It now still shows up in the Azure portal, but I'm unable to view it's details to delete it. (The bot in question is circled red in the screenshot).

I'm assume this is because it doesn't really exist anymore.

Below are attached Screenshots of my botframework view and my azure portal. I've censored some identifying information.

[image: botframework.com Screenshot]
[image: Azure Portal Screenshot]

Comment: Please contact Azure support via the Azure website to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I received from the Azure Support Team, which worked for me:

• Open Azure PowerShell, and run the following command. In case you have not configured Azure PowerShell then you can follow [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-5.2.0).

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "<your subscription id>"
Remove-AzureRmWebApp -Name "<name of your bot>" -ResourceGroupName "<name of your resourcegroup>" -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli):

az resource delete --ids /subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/mybot